# Java printing text using x,y coordinates

Tags: java

First I made class Rectangle, which gets constructor parameter x-coordinate, y-coordinate, width and height. After that I made class Grid, where I can add rectangles and it will write them in grid. Output should be this kind of:

Input now:

```
Grid r = new Grid();
r.add(new Grid(0, 0, 2, 3));
r.add(new Grid(3, 2, 4, 2));
System.out.println(r);
```

Output now:

```
xx
xx
xx
xxxx
xxxx
```

Output should be:

```
xx
xx
xx xxxx
   xxxx
```

What I should do to my code so it would take into account the x,y coordinates? Here is my "Grid" class:

```
public class Grid {

    private Rectangle rectangle;
    private ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles;

    public Grid() {
        this.rectangles = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(Rectangle rectangle) {
        int x = rectangle.getXcoordinate();
        int y = rectangle.getYcoordinate();
        int width = rectangle.getWidth();
        int height = rectangle.getHeight();
        rectangles.add(new Rectangle(x,y,width,height));
    }

    public String getTangle() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Rectangle rectangle : rectangles) {
            int x = rectangle.getXcoordinate();
            int y = rectangle.getYcoordinate();
            int width = rectangle.getWidth();
            int height= rectangle.getHeight();
            int counter = 1;
            while (height >= counter) {
                int i = 1;
                while (i <= width) {
                    sb.append("x");
                    i++;
                }
                sb.append("\n");
                counter++;   
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getTangle();
    }
}
```

Comment: what r.lisaa() does ?

Comment: @DeepakGunasekaran see the edit, typo there!

Comment: Also, seems you have missed parameterized `Grid` constructor

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)